# How do I print a bunch of OpenOffice.org documents at once?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, printing, openoffice

With Microsoft Word on Windows, I can select a bunch of documents, right-click, and select "print". There doesn't seem to be any such option for OpenOffice.org running on Ubuntu 9.10. I have a folder of about 40 documents that I want to print--is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/91779/how-can-i-convert-an-openoffice-document-to-pdf-from-the-linux-command-line), you could do this with a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $(ls ~/yourdocs/); do
    ooffice -pt pdfprinter $file
done
```